# I need to build a powershell that creates a url shortcut and opens to google chrome

Tags: powershell, url, shortcut

I have very basic knowledge in creating scripts and self taught.

I need to build a powershell that creates a url shortcut and opens to google chrome

The Website has some features that currently only work in chrome

I have created a foundation for creating the icon but need help telling it to open only through Chrome and not the default browser

```
$new_object = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$destination = $new_object.SpecialFolders.Item("AllUsersDesktop")
$source_path = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath "\\Procore Login.url"
$source = $new_object.CreateShortcut($source_path)
$source.TargetPath = "https://login.procore.com/"
$source.Save()
```

Comment: A .url shortcut will open in the users default browser. If you want chrome,  create a .lnk shortcut with `.TargetPath` pointing to the chrome.exe and set the Arguments to the url you want it to open

Comment: Are your trying to save to "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Procore Login.url".? 
look at  https://powershellmagazine.com/2013/10/30/pstip-working-with-special-folders/
 I think you want to save to something like ```$ShouldBeFilePath = [environment]::getfolderpath("Desktop") + '\' + 'ShouldBeFile.url'```
  And why not save as .html file type?

Comment: Do you really need a shortcut?  If not, just use `[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome","https://login.procore.com/")`

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I should have been more clear that the purpose of creating this is to have a script that I can upload to Intune/Azure and create the shortcut on end user's desktops

Answer (score 2):

As commented, if you create a `.url` internet shortcut, this wil open in whatever the user has set to be the default browser.

If you want to always have that url open in chrome, you need to create a `.lnk` shortcut where you set it to start chrome.exe with the wanted url as target to open.

For that you can use below helper function:

```
function New-Shortcut {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$TargetPath,                # the path to the executable
        # the rest is all optional
        [string]$ShortcutPath = (Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'New Shortcut.lnk'),
        [string[]]$Arguments = $null,       # a string or string array holding the optional arguments.
        [string[]]$HotKey = $null,          # a string like "CTRL+SHIFT+F" or an array like 'CTRL','SHIFT','F'
        [string]$WorkingDirectory = $null,
        [string]$Description = $null,
        [string]$IconLocation = $null,      # a string like "notepad.exe, 0"
        [ValidateSet('Default','Maximized','Minimized')]
        [string]$WindowStyle = 'Default',
        [switch]$RunAsAdmin
    )
    switch ($WindowStyle) {
        'Default'   { $style = 1; break }
        'Maximized' { $style = 3; break }
        'Minimized' { $style = 7 }
    }
    $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

    # create a new shortcut
    $shortcut             = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
    $shortcut.TargetPath  = $TargetPath
    $shortcut.WindowStyle = $style
    if ($Arguments)        { $shortcut.Arguments = $Arguments -join ' ' }
    if ($HotKey)           { $shortcut.Hotkey = ($HotKey -join '+').ToUpperInvariant() }
    if ($IconLocation)     { $shortcut.IconLocation = $IconLocation }
    if ($Description)      { $shortcut.Description = $Description }
    if ($WorkingDirectory) { $shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $WorkingDirectory }

    # save the link file
    $shortcut.Save()

    if ($RunAsAdmin) {
        # read the shortcut file we have just created as [byte[]]
        [byte[]]$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ShortcutPath)
        # set bit 6 of byte 21 ON
        # ([math]::Pow(2,5) or 1 -shl 5 --> 32)
        # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943
        # page 13
        $bytes[21] = $bytes[21] -bor 32
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($ShortcutPath, $bytes)
    }

    # clean up the COM objects
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shortcut) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WshShell) | Out-Null
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$chromePath = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)'
$props = @{
    'ShortcutPath' = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'Procore Login.lnk'
    'TargetPath'   = $chromePath
    'Arguments'    = 'https://login.procore.com/'
}

New-Shortcut @props
```

Comment: Nice, but `$Arguments -join ' '` is too simple, as it won't work with arguments that have embedded spaces, `"` chars., ...

Comment: So, this is interesting. When I look at the shortcut properties I see everything combined in the Target field. But when I look at it programmatically I get
`TargetPath:  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
`Arguments:  -nologo -noExit -executionpolicy bypass -file "\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 3.#\# Dev 3.4.5\Resources\PxUtility_InventorySoftware.ps1"
 -r:"T -notin Appx, P -lk Autodesk*, iD -lt 1W" -o:"O_X"`

Comment: But when I manually try to add more arguments it stops at 259 total characters. And if I try to add text in code it truncates at the same 259 characters, with no error. Which, seriously Microsoft? WTAF?

Comment: In any case, it looks like the combined limit of `.TargetPath` & `.Arguments` is 260 characters less one terminating character. And since Microsoft won't let me shorten `.TargetPath`, nor does Microsoft provide (too my knowledge) terse versions of arguments like `-executionpolicy bypass` that I need, and I can't control, just influence the script path in `-file`, I am back to just making my own arguments so terse as to be almost unreadable. Love ya Microsoft. Seriously.

Comment: All that said, knowing some of these details of Shortcut manipulation is going to be super useful. Thanks!