# Limitations of Target field in windows LNKs

Tags: powershell, shortcut-file

I am attempting to use a shortcut to a powershell script, which has to be run elevated, and has some arguments which can be somewhat long. And the location of the script itself may be in a rather buried folder since Architects really like to have massive folder structures. The issue is I am running out of room. And Microsoft using 57 characters for `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` is not helping.
I also can't use the `Start in:` to provide the path to the script. My guess is I am just hosed by Microsoft's limitations in shortcuts, but I wonder if someone knows some secret sauce for doing something like, maybe forcing the shortcut to just use `powershell.exe` rather than the full path?
Or is my only option to get as terse as I possible can with my arguments?

Comment: What limit, specifically, are you running into?

Comment: @mklement0 total characters. I am running out of them. :) This is target line I have now, with 248 characters. :(
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -noExit -executionpolicy bypass -file "\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 3.#\# Dev 3.4.5\Resources\PxUtility_InventorySoftware.ps1" -r:"T -notin Appx, P -lk Autodesk*, iD -lt 1W" -o:"O_X"`
That structure is much more concise than some firms I have seen.

Comment: Most of this stuff (actually everything after powershell.exe) should go into the `Arguments`, not the `TargetPath`

Comment: @Theo Arguments? My LNK properties, under the Shortcut tab, has Target:, Start in:, a Run: drop down, and Comment:. Is there some secret sauce to enable another field for arguments? That would be awesome!

Comment: @Gordon Yes, there are more properties you can set in a shortcut. See my function `New-Shortcut` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304164/9898643)

Comment: Did Theo's linked answer solves your issue? If so we could close this as a duplicate

Comment: So, this seems interesting. When I manually look at the properties of my shortcut, I see the combined info in the `Target:` field. But when I use @Theo 's code to just look at the data, `.TargetPath` and `.Arguments` are shown separated. BUT, if I try to append to the `.Arguments` such that the combined character count exceeds 259 characters, it truncates `.Arguments` and throws no error. So, I seem to still be limited, but I do wonder if you guys are seeing the same behavior?